# Unexpected Crash When trying to open the detailactivity

Tags: java, android

I am facing a strange problem in my material design app . Some thumbnails are opening and loading details activity as expected , but some are not opening instead there is crash happening . in this video u can see the problem I am facing .
I am attaching the link to my project ZIP file link with this ,[My Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1toGC5YbWBe6KNs7vdzDBBGgyOWwCl_fK)

this is the main activity ....

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ReaderAdapter.ReaderOnClickItemHandler {
public final static String READER_DATA = "reader";
public final static String POSITION = "position";
private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String SAVED_ARRAYLIST = "saved_array_list";
private static final String SAVED_LAYOUT_MANAGER = "layout-manager-state";
private ApiInterface mApiInterface;
private List<Reader> mNetworkDataList;
@BindView(R.id.main_recycler_view)
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
@BindView(R.id.main_linear_layout)
LinearLayout mErrorLinearLayout;
@BindView(R.id.main_progress_bar)
ProgressBar mProgressBar;
@BindView(R.id.toolbar_main)
Toolbar toolbar;
@BindView(R.id.main_reload_button)
Button mButton;
private ReaderAdapter mReaderAdapter;
private Parcelable onSavedInstanceState = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    if (null != toolbar) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    }
    mApiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    mReaderAdapter = new ReaderAdapter(this, this);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mReaderAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    // getting the data from api using retrofit interface ApiInterface
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        onSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(SAVED_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
        mNetworkDataList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(SAVED_ARRAYLIST);
    }
    if (null == mNetworkDataList) {

        loadData();

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadData();
            }
        });
    }else {
        loadAdapter();
    }
}

public void loadData() {
    final Call<List<Reader>> listCall = mApiInterface.getAllReaderData();
    // now binding the data in the pojo class
    listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Reader>>() {
        //if data is successfully binded from json to the pojo class onResponse is called
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Reader>> call,
                               Response<List<Reader>> response) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Response : " + response.code());
            mNetworkDataList = response.body();
            loadAdapter();
        }

        //if data binding is not successful onFailed called
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Reader>> call, Throwable t) {
            //cancelling the GET data request
            listCall.cancel();
            showError();
        }
    });
}

private void loadAdapter() {
    if (null != mNetworkDataList) {
        showReaderList();
        mReaderAdapter.ifDataChanged(mNetworkDataList);
        if (onSavedInstanceState != null) {
            mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(onSavedInstanceState);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * this method is for showing the error textview and making all other views gone
 */
private void showError() {
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mErrorLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

/**
 * this method is for showing the recyclerview and making all other views gone
 */
private void showReaderList() {
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mErrorLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}




private int numberOfColumns() {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    // You can change this divider to adjust the size of the poster
    int widthDivider = 400;
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int nColumns = width / widthDivider;
    if (nColumns < 2) return 2;
    return nColumns;
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable(SAVED_LAYOUT_MANAGER, mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()
            .onSaveInstanceState());
    if (mNetworkDataList != null)
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(SAVED_ARRAYLIST, new ArrayList<Parcelable>(mNetworkDataList));

}

@Override
public void onClickItem(int position, Reader reader, ImageView mImage, TextView mTitle) {
    // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher

    Intent readerIntent = new Intent(this, ReaderDetailsActivity.class);
    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    mBundle.putParcelable(READER_DATA, reader);
    mBundle.putInt(POSITION, position);
    readerIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // Apply activity transition
        ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                this,
                // Now we provide a list of Pair items which contain the view we can transitioning
                // from, and the name of the view it is transitioning to, in the launched activity
                new Pair<View, String>(mImage,
                        ReaderDetailsActivity.VIEW_NAME_HEADER_IMAGE),
                new Pair<View, String>(mTitle,
                        ReaderDetailsActivity.VIEW_NAME_HEADER_TITLE));
        ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, readerIntent, activityOptions.toBundle());

    } else {
        // Swap without transition
        startActivity(readerIntent);
    }

}
```

}
this is details activity ......

```
public class ReaderDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = ReaderDetailsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String SAVED_ARRAYLIST = "saved_array_list";
private static final String SAVED_LAYOUT_MANAGER = "layout-manager-state";
private final static String ARTICLE_SCROLL_POSITION = "article_scroll_position";
// View name of the header image. Used for activity scene transitions
public static final String VIEW_NAME_HEADER_IMAGE = "detail:header:image";

// View name of the header title. Used for activity scene transitions
public static final String VIEW_NAME_HEADER_TITLE = "detail:header:title";

private int position;
private Reader reader;
private int[] scrollPosition = null;
@BindView(R.id.scrollView_details)
ScrollView mScrollView;
@BindView(R.id.details_fragment_title)
TextView mTitle;
@BindView(R.id.imageView_details)
ImageView mImageView;
@BindView(R.id.textView_author_details)
TextView mAuthor;
@BindView(R.id.textView_published_date)
TextView mPublishDate;
@BindView(R.id.textView_description)
TextView mDescription;
@BindView(R.id.floatingActionButton_Up)
FloatingActionButton mFloatingActionButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader_details);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    position=0;
    mFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
        }
    });
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(mImageView, VIEW_NAME_HEADER_IMAGE);
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(mTitle, VIEW_NAME_HEADER_TITLE);
    if (null != bundle) {
        position = bundle.getInt(MainActivity.POSITION);
        reader = bundle.getParcelable(MainActivity.READER_DATA);
        if(null != reader) {
            mTitle.setText(reader.getTitle());
            mPublishDate.setText(reader.getPublishedDate());
            mAuthor.setText(reader.getAuthor());
            GlideApp.with(this)
                    .load(reader.getPhoto())
                    .into(mImageView);
            mDescription.setText(reader.getBody());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    scrollPosition = savedInstanceState.getIntArray(ARTICLE_SCROLL_POSITION);
    if (scrollPosition != null) {
        mScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mScrollView.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[0]);
            }
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

}

[Json link](https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/March/58c5d68f_xyz-reader/xyz-reader.json)  I am parsing for this project .

Here is a screen recording of my project where u can see the problem I am facing , [recording](https://photos.app.goo.gl/vqQTAWYc9oJTe3TY6)

this is a console log when I am trying to debug ....
when it is working fine the console log is `08/09 20:31:31: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of /home/soumyajit/AndroidStudioProjects/MaterialReader/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop lordsomen.android.com.materialreader
$ adb shell am start -n "lordsomen.android.com.materialreader/lordsomen.android.com.materialreader.activities.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Connecting to lordsomen.android.com.materialreader
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'`

and when it is crashing the console log is

`08/09 20:31:31: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of /home/soumyajit/AndroidStudioProjects/MaterialReader/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop lordsomen.android.com.materialreader
$ adb shell am start -n "lordsomen.android.com.materialreader/lordsomen.android.com.materialreader.activities.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Connecting to lordsomen.android.com.materialreader
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'`

thanks in advance ..

Comment: add your crash logs

Comment: actually it is showing nothing , no error , otherwise   I will add the crash logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum Parcelable size should not be exceed 1mb. In you app it is 2.1 Mb. Without passing app date to the next activity you can try to pass item id and load data in next activity. Otherwise you can cache the list data and you can load the data from the local database in the details activity. If you cannot see crash log in android studio it because it set as "show only selected activity". In this case app get close and then this type of logs doesnot show in the android studio. switch that to No Filter and you can see the all logs.